# TNS command not found after installing NativeScript

Tags: command-line, terminal, nativescript

I updated NPM and Node before installing NativeScript, without errors I might add, but when I attempt to create a new project using `tns create MyProjectName`, I get the error `tns command not found`.

After much reading, I'm getting the feeling it has something to do with my `PATH`.

This is what is outputted in terminal during the NativeScript install regarding TNS:

```
sudo npm install -g nativescript --unsafe-perm

/Users/martingeldart/.npm-global/bin/tns -> /Users/martingeldart/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns
/Users/martingeldart/.npm-global/bin/nativescript -> /Users/martingeldart/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns
...
```

If I run `echo $PATH`, this is what outputs:

```
echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin
```

Which looks really odd to me but I'm no command line expert by any means. In fact, I'm incredibly inexperienced with the whole command line system.

Why am I not able to access the `tns` command? What is going on with that PATH I echoed?

MacOSX

Comment: What is your current version of npm?

Comment: @Plpicard Sorry, 6.14.5

Answer (score 1):

Between version of npm the location of the global package moved location in the OS.  Since the installation has moved the terminal does not know where to find the command.  The PATH variable is used to tell the terminal where all the command may be located.  In this case this seems a standard.
Now the best way to access command from an installed package is to use `npx` which is included by default with the new installation of npm.

https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally

```
npx tns
# In your case
npx tns create MyProjectName
```

There 2 other ways to resolve this.

1. Either your global package folder is not set up correctly.
   https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally
2. Add the bin folder where nativescript was install to your path manually (usually in .bash_profile), open a new terminal.

I use nativescript for various project and I have a suggestion for package management.  Usually I avoid installing global package because in case of multiple project there may be conflict between version if some project are updated and other not.

I usually create a folder with the version I am installing.  Go to the folder, npm init and install locally the package.

```
mkdir nativescript-project-6-0
cd nativescript-project-6-0
npm init
npm i --save nativescript
```

Now I have a fix version to work with and can create other project with the same version even if I have other project with newer version of the tool or lib.  Now in  nativescript-project-6-0 I create my project.

```
npx tns create MyProjectName
```

This should create a folder `nativescript-project-6-0/MyProjectName`. All set and ready to go.  Remember that is is always a good idea to use `npx` in this case since we want to use the local package.